# #1064 SQL error

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I recently started learning some laravel and I am following this guide :

http://www.packtpub.com/article/laravel4-creating-a-simple-crud-application-in-hours

However , I am getting sql syntax error when I try to create the database. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem in this query?

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'users' (
  'id' int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  'username' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'password' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'email' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'phone' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'name' varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  'created_at' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  'updated_at' timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY ('id')
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Comment: If it is for create database or table?

Comment: You're using quotes around columns' names and table name, use backticks.

Comment: This is for table creation

Comment: Unfortunately, whoever wrote [**that guide**](http://www.packtpub.com/article/laravel4-creating-a-simple-crud-application-in-hours) is outright **wrong** and should be updated or deleted from the Web. Use any of the answers given below, as well as my comment above. To think that that information is inside a book they're selling; they should be ashamed of themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `''` across the column names and table name, you have added `''` for table name and column names which is invalid. you can use backticks if you want, but not needed unless you are using some reserved keywords

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  username varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  password varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  email varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  phone varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Error 1064 is unexpected litteral, you've got single quotes(`'`) around your table and column names, not backticks(`` ` ``).

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

**Your Query is working Perfectly Except ''**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
      id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      username varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      password varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      email varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      phone varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      name varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      updated_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
     AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

****select * from users****
```